# Show XML in WebBrowser without save temp file

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application where I need to show a XML content in a TextBox or in a WebBrowser control, but this XML is stored compressed in database.

I found some tutorials and questions where people take the XML string, save it on temporary file then calls the Navigate method, passing this temporary file path. However, my application is Silverlight on client side, so I may have permissions problems storing temporary files on user's machine.

Showing the string in a TextBox it's an option, but the problem is that the XML content may be compressed,so it's difficult to read.

I know I can save this file on server, then deliver this file URL to my Silverlight application, then open a Browser window, but I'm just looking for a simple solution to do entirely on client side.

Is there some simple way to format(uncompress) this XML, or a simple way to open this string in WebBrowser as XML wihout saving a temporary file?

Comment: Is it compressed, or is it not indented? You should be able to set the content in the web browser control manually, therefore get the xml string and just write the xml content in the browser control. I used to navigate to about:blank first so the browser has a window object and a document object

Comment: I think I meant not indented. I need to show it indented, like when you open a XML file with Internet Explorer for instance. Indenting the string is an solution so I just display it in a TextBox.

Comment: Just try to write the xml content into the browser control. I am sure you can find how to do it.

Comment: Yeah, the silverlight browser control has a NavigateToString() method. You can pass it your xml content

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx